# Missing Dependencies for SOCKS support

Tags: python, http, sockets, proxy

Trying to use a proxy with requests.get and returning Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.  requests[socks] and pysocks are installed.  I've tried http and https with the same error.
Python 3.11

```
import requests
from socks import requests


#Fill in your own proxies' details
proxies={'http':'socks5://myinfo',
      'https':'socks5://myinfo'}

# Make HTTP request using the proxy
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get('http://neverssl.com', headers = headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=15)
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing request twice, just change the name of the import like this:

```
import requests
import socks

proxies = {'http': 'socks5://myinfo',
'https': 'socks5://myinfo'}

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, 'myinfo', 1080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get('http://neverssl.com', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=15)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Same result.  Also the import socks is darkened with the notation that socks is not accessed by pylance.

Comment: Maybe it is the socks library that is not imported correctly, I updated my code

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled the library. same result.

Comment: Adding more info:
in SOCKSProxyManager(*args, **kwargs)
     61 def SOCKSProxyManager(*args, **kwargs):
---> 62     raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")

InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.

Comment: Now it look like a pysocks library problem, check if you have it pip install pysocks, check the last version pip install --upgrade pysocks, if that still dont work uninstall and re install pip uninstall pysocks

Comment: I have it installed.  I tried previously to uninstall and reinstall and did it again.  Still the same response.
I do appreciate your time to help me with this.

Comment: Try to do all this inside a virtual environment like venv, at least we will know if it is a package problem

Comment: opened in a new venv, installed requests and pysocks.  ran the script and still received the same error.

Comment: Try to isolate the problematic import, still in an environment take your script and add each part one by one till it first fail